Finding minimum pairs from given input
I have a string s of length n made of only 3 characters 0, 1, and !, and two numbers provided as x and y
Now I have to replace ! with 0 or 1
Then count number of subsequences 01 say count1 and also 10 say count2
Now calculate the sum = (x * count1) + (y * count2)
Find the minimum possible sum.
Output can be large so return result mod 10^9 + 7.
Example:
s = "101!1", x = 2, y = 3

Result = 9

Explanation:
case 1:

Replace '!' with '0' then we get "10101"
number of "01" subsequences are count1 = 3 at indices (1,2), (1,4), (3,4) 
number of "10" subsequences are count2 = 3 at indices (0,1), (0,3), (2,3)

Sum =  (x * count1) + (y * count2) = 2*3 + 3*3 = 15

case 2:

Replace '!' with '1' then we get "10111"
number of "01" subsequences are count1 = 3 at indices (1,2), (1,3), (1,4) 
number of "10" subsequences are count2 = 1 at indices (0,1)

Sum =  (x * count1) + (y * count2) = 2*3 + 3*1 = 9

Result min(15, 9) = 9

Another example:
n = 7, s = "!!!!!!!", x = 23, y = 47

Result = 0

Explanation:
Replace '!' with '0' then we get "0000000"
number of "01" subsequences are count1 = 0
number of "10" subsequences are count2 = 0

Sum = 23 * 0 + 47 * 0 = 0

Replace '!' with '1' then we get "1111111"
number of "01" subsequences are count1 = 0
number of "10" subsequences are count2 = 0

Sum = 23 * 0 + 47 * 0

Result = min(0, 0) = 0

Constraints:
`n` ranges from 1 to 10^5
values of x and y range is [0, 10^5]

Here is my code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve("101!1",2,3));//9
    System.out.println(solve("!!!!!!!",23,47));//0
}

static int solve(String s, int x, int y) {
    long zero = 0, one = 0;
    long count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    int mod = 1000_000_007;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == '1') {
            one = (one + 1 ) %mod;
            count1 = (count1 + zero) % mod;
        } else {
            zero = (zero + 1) % mod;
            count2 = (count2 + one) % mod;
        }
    }
    long sum1 = ((count1 * x)%mod + (count2 * y) % mod)%mod;
    zero = 0;
    one = 0;
    count1 = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == '1' || c == '!') {
            one = (one + 1 ) %mod;
            count1 = (count1 + zero) % mod;
        } else {
            zero = (zero + 1) % mod;
            count2 = (count2 + one) % mod;
        }
    }
    long sum2 = ((count1 * x)%mod + (count2 * y) % mod)%mod;
    return (int) Math.min(sum1, sum2);
}

I got this question during a hackerrank interview, I was able to solve partially and got 13 test cases passed out of 15 with my above code.
The remaining two test cases failed with wrong output, for those 2 test cases, the input string is having length of 1,00,000 so I was not able to debug why my code is failing.
What is the correct approach to solve this problem.

I would first suspect some overflow...

@user85421, I also suspected the same, so I have used %mod for every operation, still not able to find why its failing.

@user85421, for 001 we get 2 subsequences of 01 and 0 subsequences of 10, I see that my code is generating correct counts only. Same applies to 011, we have 2 01 and 0 10

ah, I misunderstood the problem, was thinking of substring instead of subsequence (the examples are clear) - then the overflow is even more probable

but using long should avoid the overflow, considering that x and y aren't too big (10^5) -- try using Math.addExact() and Math.multiplyExact() to be sure there is no overflow

It looks like your algorithm either replaces all ! with 0 or all ! with 1. I'm pretty sure such an approach would not work in general.

Do you happen to have a link to the hackerrank question?

@wLui155, as I understand, the objective is determine which returns the smaller weighted average: replacing all '!'s with '0's or all '!'s with '1's.

Do you mean you were asked this Hackerrank problem during a job interview or were you asked this question when applying for a job with Hackerrank? If the former could you provide a link to  the Hackerrank problem? Your question is clear to me but it would be helpful for members to be able to test their code at the Hackerrank site (assuming case #1 applies).

@CarySwoveland, I was asked when applying for a job. I don't have link for the problem to share.

@wLui155, can you please share your approach to solve this problem.

Although a Java answer is requested, the problem is principally concerned with the algorithm to be employed. Considering also that I have no experience with Java, I will offer a solution in Ruby, which, with some explanations I will provide along the way, can be viewed as pseudo-code, which I assume can be converted to Java fairly easily.
I have chosen to omit the modulo calculations for clarity.
First I will construct a method cnt01 which returns the number of '0'-'1' sequences for a string held by the variable str when the value of the explanation point (a.k.a. "mark") is given by expl_pt.
def cnt01(str, excl_pt)
  zeroes = 0
  cnt = 0
  str.each_char do |c|
    if c == '0' || (c == '!' && excl_pt == '0')
      zeroes += 1
    else # c == '1' || (c == '!' && excl_pt == '1')
      cnt = cnt + zeroes
    end
  end
  cnt
end

if c == '0' || (c == '!' && excl_pt == '0') reads, if not obvious, "if c equals '0' or both c equals '!' and excl_pt equals '0'". The method returns cnt
Some examples:
cnt01('0101101', '0') #=> 8
cnt01('!1!11!1', '0') #=> 8

cnt01('0101001', '1') #=> 7
cnt01('0!0100!', '1') #=> 7


Next I will construct the method cnt10, which returns the number of '1'-'0' sequences for a string held by the variable str when the value of the explanation point is given by expl_pt. This is most easily done by first creating a helper method that converts '0's to '1's and '1's to '0's.
def flip(str)
  str.gsub(/[01]/) do |s|
    s == '0' ? '1' : '0'
  end
end

This method converts characters that match the regular expression /[01]/ ('0' and '1', but not '!') from '0' to '1' and from '1' to '0'.
Some examples:
flip('0101001') #=> "1010110"
flip('0!0100!') #=> "1!1011!"
flip('0')       #=> "1"
flip('1')       #=> "0"


We may then write
def cnt10(str, expl_pt)
  cnt01(flip(str), flip(expl_pt))
end

as this simply involves a relabelling of characters.
cnt10('0101101', '0') #=> 4
cnt10('!1!11!1', '0') #=> 4

cnt10('0101001', '1') #=> 5
cnt10('0!0100!', '1') #=> 5


The main method, wt_cnt follows easily.
def wt_cnt(str, expl_pt, x, y)
  x * cnt01(str, expl_pt) + y * cnt10(str, expl_pt)
end

For example,
x = 2
y = 3
str = '1!1011!'

wt_cnt(str, '0', x, y) #=> 31 (2*5 + 3*7)
wt_cnt(str, '1', x, y) #=> 15 (2*3 + 3*3)

So for this example setting the exclamation point to '1' produces the smaller total value.

Note that, whereas four passes through the string are needed, the code could be modified in the obvious way so that only two passes, or even a single pass, are needed. That would, however, adversely affect readability and complicate testing.

I found the question posted in leetcode, sharing the link here for reference: https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/4993971/AMAZON-OA-%3A-getMinErrors()

Your code assumes that a < b iff a % MOD < b % MOD, but this is not true. For example, if a = MOD and b = 1, a % MOD = 0 < 1, but a was much larger than b.
Use longs to track the intermediate calculations, but do NOT apply mod at any step. Given the input constraints, long is enough to store the results of all calculations without overflow: (1e5 choose 2) * 1e5 is much less than Long.MAX_VALUE.
At the end, check which sum was smaller, and only then apply the remainder operator.
return (int) (Math.min(sum1, sum2) % mod);


I tried this approach also, just applying mod in the end return (int) (Math.min(sum1, sum2) % mod); but same issue, 2 test cases were failing.

@Sid Without seeing the problem, anything else is just speculation, but are you sure the problem explicitly stated that all exclamation marks are to be replaced with the same character?

Based on example n = 7, s = "!!!!!!!", x = 23, y = 47, Result = 0, it should be all exclamation marks are to be replaced with the same character

@Sid That doesn't really show that all exclamation marks should be replaced with the same character. Even if you could use different characters, the optimal solution would use the same character for that test case. There might be a misunderstanding of the problem here.

I found this same question is asked in leetcode as well, please check if I am missing something, that is causing the 2 testcases to fail. https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/4993971/AMAZON-OA-%3A-getMinErrors()
